# Approximating real vectors in the unit hypercube by rational vectors in the unit hypercube

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, approximation, rational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

I am currently looking for an error bound for an problem where I have to approximate a real vector in the unit hypercube using a rational vector in the unit hypercube.

Specifically: given a $d$-dimensional real vector, $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d \cap [0,1]^d$, I would like to find a $d$-dimensional rational vector, 
$$\rho = \Bigg(\frac{p_1}{q},\ldots,\frac{p_d}{q} \Bigg) $$
where, 
$$ p_1,\ldots,p_d, q \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$ p_i \leq q ~~ \text{for} ~~ i = 1,\ldots,d$$
Note that the previous conditions simply ensure that $\rho \in\mathbb{Q}^d \cap [0,1]^d$

Given this setup, I am looking for an "error-bound" that is similar to Dirichlet's [simultaneous approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_approximation_theorem). That is, something like:

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^d \cap [0,1]^d$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose an integer $q$ so that there exists integers $p_1,\ldots,p_d$ all less or equal to $q$ such that:

$$\Bigg|\alpha_i - \frac{p_i}{q} \Bigg| < \epsilon ~~~~ \text{for} ~~ i = 1,\ldots,d$$

---

**Potentially helpful:** from the answers to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721599/existence-of-a-simultaneous-rational-approximation-of-real-numbers-in-0-1), I know that I can use Dirichlet's [simultaneous approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_approximation_theorem) to generate the following "there exists"-style error bound to my approximation problem:

Given any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^d \cap [0,1]^d$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $q > N$, there exists integers $p_1,\ldots,p_d$ all less or equal to $q$ such that:

$$ \Bigg|\alpha_i - \frac{p_i}{q}\Bigg| < \frac{1}{q^{1+ 1/d}} \text{    for } i=1,\ldots,d $$

My issue with this bound is that it only guarantees that there exists some natural number $N$ for which my error bound holds... However it does not tell me how large $N$ should be. If someone can figure out how large $N$ should be then this would work as well.